# Bootstrap v3.3 Collapse Nav at 768px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been unable to get my Bootstrap v3.3.0 nav to collapse at the 768px breakpoint.

I setup this https://jsfiddle.net/wfx35s1v/2/ to demonstrate the issue.

I added this code I found somewhere (sorry I'd provide a link if I could find the source):

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-collapse.in { overflow-y: auto !important; }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none; }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block; }
    .navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse, 
    .navbar-static-top .navbar-collapse, 
    .navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px; }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none !important; }
        .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important; 
        margin-top: 0px; }
}
```

Here's my jsFiddle fork with this snippet included:  https://jsfiddle.net/ws78kmf0/1/

The snippet forces the nav to collapse.  Which is great.  But then when you want to toggle the nav, that doesn't work.

I would appreciate help getting the nav to collapse at 768px using CSS if possible.

Comment: You forgot jQuery. Your fiddle doesn't have it included, and you likely don't have it linked on your local project. Bootstrap classes *need* jQuery for animations, transitions, etc, including the navbar's collapse/toggle. See https://jsfiddle.net/wfx35s1v/1/

Comment: Also, check your console (F12, Console Tab), it **very clearly** says: *Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery*

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I added jQuery to both jsfiddle examples. However, adding jQuery does not resolve the issue.

Comment: You also need to load bootstrap js.

Comment: As Tim Lewis says, it works fine with jQuery 2.1 and Bootstrap 3.3 as resources. Try his snippet

Comment: When I force the jsfiddle pane to be 768px in Tim's example jsfiddle.net/wfx35s1v/1 , the nav is not collapsed for me in Chrome.